# Not clear on the last step of Andrew Granville's proof of the Sylvester-Schur Theorem

Tags: prime-numbers, proof-explanation

In Appendix 5A of Andrew Granville's [Number Theory Revealed: A Masterclass](https://bookstore.ams.org/mbk-127), he presents a proof of the Sylvester-Schur Theorem.

I am unclear on the last step of the following inductive proof.

Exercise 5.10.1 is used to show that for all $n\ge k \ge 1$: $$\left(1 + \frac{1}{n+k}\right)^k \le \left(1 + \frac{k}{n+1}\right)$$

Assume that up to $n$, with $\pi(k)$ being the [prime counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function), it is shown that:
$${{n+k}\choose{k}} > (n+k)^{\pi(k)}$$

Here is the step that I am not clear on:

$${{n+1+k}\choose{k}} = \left(1 + \frac{k}{n+1}\right){{n+k}\choose{k}} > \left(1 + \frac{1}{n+k}\right)^k(n+k)^{\pi(k)} > (n+k+1)^{\pi(k)}$$

I am not clear how we can be sure that:

$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{n+k}\right)^k(n+k)^{\pi(k)} > (n+k+1)^{\pi(k)}$$

How can we be sure that this inequality holds for all $n \ge k \ge 1$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $n, k \ge 1$, since $k \gt \pi(k)$ and $1 + \frac{1}{n+k} \gt 1$, we therefore get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\left(1 + \frac{1}{n+k}\right)^k & \gt \left(1 + \frac{1}{n+k}\right)^{\pi(k)} \\
\left(1 + \frac{1}{n+k}\right)^k & \gt \left(\frac{n + k + 1}{n+k}\right)^{\pi(k)} \\
\left(1 + \frac{1}{n+k}\right)^k(n + k)^{\pi(k)} & \gt (n + k + 1)^{\pi(k)}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$